# "Undefined reference" error when using custom destructor

Tags: c++, root-framework

I'm trying to write a class that needs to deallocate some memory, so I've defined a custom destructor. This is compiled as a shared library. However, when I try to compile a basic program to use that library, I'm getting the usual "undefined reference" error when a definition cannot be found. If I remove the destructor, this does not occur.

Here's a stripped-down example:

Header file:

```
#ifndef _SKYMAP_H_
#define _SKYMAP_H_

#include <vector>
#include "TCanvas.h"

class BL_Skymap {
 public:
   BL_Skymap();
   ~BL_Skymap();

 protected:
   TCanvas mCanvas;
};

#endif //_BENSLIBRARY_SKYMAP_H_
```

Source file:

```
\#include "BL_Skymap.h"

BL_Skymap::BL_Skymap()
{
}

BL_Skymap::~BL_Skymap()
{
}
```

Now the program I'm using is simply this:

```
\#include "BL_Skymap.h"

int main()
{
  BL_Skymap map;
  return(0);
}
```

Note that I'm using the ROOT analysis package (that's the TCanvas object). When I compile the small program above, I get the following errors (the Skymap class is compiled into libMyLibrary.so):

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lMyLibrary `root-config --cflags --glibs`
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libMyLibrary.so: undefined reference to 'TCanvas::~TCanvas()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libMyLibrary.so: undefined reference to 'TCanvas::TCanvas(bool)'
```

Please note that the root package gives a utility to generate the required compiler flags, which is the purpose of `root-config --cflags --glibs` above.
What am I missing here?

UPDATE: I've written a Makefile to perform the compilation of my library, which executes the following:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic --std=c++11 -Isrc -Ihdr -MM -MT 'obj/BL_Skymap.o' src/BL_Skymap.cpp -MF BL_Skymap.d `root-config --cflags --glibs`
g++ -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic --std=c++11 -Isrc -Ihdr -fPIC -o obj/BL_Skymap.o -c src/BL_Skymap.cpp `root-config --cflags --glibs`
g++ -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic --std=c++11 -shared obj/*.o -o libMyLibrary.so
```

UPDATE2: I found the problem - in the final step in the compilation above, I was forgetting to add the call to `root-config` and therefore `libMyLibrary.so` wasn't linking to the ROOT libraries like it should have.

Comment: What output does `root-config --cflags --glibs` actually produce?

Comment: It's obviously that TCanvas's constructor/destructor is missing, so you probably should know what `root-config --cflags --glibs` produce.

Comment: On my system, this is the output:

`-pthread -m64 -I/home/bwhelan/work/Auger/Software/External/root/5.34.03/include/root -L/home/bwhelan/work/Auger/Software/External/root/5.34.03/lib/root -lGui -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic`

I use it regularly, which is why I am stumped here.

Comment: So where is TCanvas implemented? The issue is just you're missing to link a object/library that includes TCanvas's implementation.

Comment: It's implemented in the ROOT package, I believe in the Gpad library. What I don't understand is that if I remove the destructor, this problem disappears, which makes me think it's not as simple as a missing link.

Comment: So you mean if removing `~BL_Skymap()`, the code can be compiled, but with it, you get link error? That sounds weird...

Comment: That's correct, and also why I'm confused!

Comment: Try using -lMyLibrary at the end of the command line. - That the problem goes away if you don't have a destructor may be due to things being optimized away. nm may show the symbols in the .o file.

Comment: I've already tried that, and unfortunately it does not work.

As an interesting update, I found that adding `TCanvas canv;` and nothing else in the test.cpp file circumvents this error.

Comment: it's odd that it doen't complain about the missing constructor, have you tried adding a function `foo` and calling it in `main`?

Comment: /home/bwhelan/work/Auger/Software/External/root/5.34.03/lib/root - these libraries are static libraries? I never tried to have a shared library depend on static libraries. When would that be resolved? The fact that adding Tcanvas canv; to the main program removes the problem is highly suggestive:that pulls it into the compiled and linked program, and so the missing ref in the library is satisfied.

Comment: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2006-03/msg00005.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is certainly good to be aware of. However, all of the libraries are shared (i.e. they're .so files) - the one I create as well as the ROOT libraries.

Comment: Hmmm, my previous answer didn't make too much sense, after all. Could you show the command line you used to compile the library?

Comment: No problems, I've updated above.

Comment: Ah, found the problem - I'd neglected to add the `root-config` command to the creation of the .so file, although it was present elsewhere. A silly mistake, thanks for the help in diagnosing it!

rodrigo, is there a way I can give you the bounty? It was your questions that made me realise the problem.

Comment: @Wheels2050: Ehh, I appreciate the intention, but my actual, deleted answer was a mess. You can reply to your own question, but I'm afraid that you cannot reward yourself with the bounty ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in an update to the original question, my problem was that I was using the relevant flags for the ROOT libraries when I was compiling the BL_Skymap.o object file, but not when I was linking the object file together to make the libMyLibrary.so file.

Adding the ROOT flags to this final step fixed the problem.